# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"''

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyaudio

I want to install package PyAudio
i have downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

```
pip install PyAudio
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sr306wg6\\pyaudio_6f7053cacf7449edbc9d6ffc2af1c1b7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sr306wg6\\pyaudio_6f7053cacf7449edbc9d6ffc2af1c1b7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4a7_eg67\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sr306wg6\pyaudio_6f7053cacf7449edbc9d6ffc2af1c1b7\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: MS_WIN64: Ё§¬Ґ­Ґ­ЁҐ ¬ Єа®®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: б¬. ЇаҐ¤л¤гйҐҐ ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­ЁҐ "MS_WIN64"
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sr306wg6\\pyaudio_6f7053cacf7449edbc9d6ffc2af1c1b7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-sr306wg6\\pyaudio_6f7053cacf7449edbc9d6ffc2af1c1b7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4a7_eg67\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: `portaudio.h: No such file or directory` is the immediate error, and it means exactly what it says -- specifically, that you don't have the portaudio development headers installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpyaudio%5D+fatal+error+C1083+portaudio.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me once when I was making a voice recognition app.
What I did was I went to a website with unofficial python binaries but it was a pain. Instead, if you are on a windows system, which you appear to be on, use

```
pip install pipwin && pipwin install pyaudio
```

Then you have to wait for 5-10 minutes for pipwin to build it's cache and then it will install.